# Very simple Mongo .save gives no error and saves no record

Tags: mongoose

I tried several examples from here, but none seems to work. 
I must be missing a small important thing.

This is my model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema   = mongoose.Schema;
var mySchema = new Schema({
    _id:  Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
    foo:  String,
    bar:  String
}, { versionKey: false }); 
module.exports = mongoose.model('myModel', mySchema, 'my');
```

And this is my code

```
let myModel= require('/models/myModel');

let myRec = new myModel({
    "foo" : "whatever",
    "bar" : "whatever"
});

myRec.save(function (err, res) {  
    if (err) {
        console.log("ERROR " + err);
    } else {
        console.log("Saved " + res);
    }
})
```

I dont get ERROR or Saved, and it does not save anything in the database either.

Can anyone see what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have explicitly declared the `_id` field in your `Schema` while creating a document you need to pass the `_id` field also. You can remove `_id` if you want so Mongoose will automatically create `_id` of type `ObjectId` for the document

Comment: Ahhhh.... that was it!! - I remembered that Mongo automatically created the _id - but I forgot it only did that when the _id is NOT defined :D   Damn!!  So simple :)  Thanks!!

Comment: (could have been nice if mongo threw an error or crashed or gave me electric shock or... something! hehehe)

Comment: Yes, it actually throws an error saying something like `document must have _id`. Since you are logging the error you should be able to see it in the console